# Calling a php function on page load

Tags: php, load

Hi I have the following php code that I would like to be able to have it fire on page load. Any idea how this can be done.

action('clear_session')?>

thanks Maria

Comment: php runs on the server, javascript runs on the client. you cannot have one directly invoke the other. Try AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server, but the PagLoad event occurs on the client. You can't directly call a PHP function from the PageLoad event. You might be able to do what you want while PHP is generating the page, or you could perhaps use an AJAX call to achieve the desired result.